# Prevent caching of the ajax response

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I have just started working with HTML and java script. I am stuck up in between. I have created one Web Page which reads data from XML and displays on the page. I am able to do it successfully. But if i am changes XML data and refresh the browser it is not reflecting updated Data on my web page. If i clear my browser history manually and then refresh the page it will display the  updated data.But i wants data to be updated as soon as i refresh the page.I don't wants to clear browser history every time.

My server is Apache server.

My html Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "- HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<TITLE>DynamicHTML Page</TITLE>

<META content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv=Content-Type> 
<META http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="10";>
<META name=Author content="">
<META name=Keywords content="">

 <body>

 </div>
<xml ID="noteXML"
SRC="note.xml"></xml>
<script>

function ReadXML()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","note.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

document.getElementById("data").innerHTML= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("data")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("status")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

}

 </script>

 <div>
 <b>Require Data :</b>  <span id="data"></span><br />

 <div>
 <b>Current Status:</b> <span id="status"></span><br />

<script>
ReadXML();
</script>
</body>
 </html>
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<note>
<data> 450 </data>
<status> Reading Data From XML </status>
</note>
```

I have also tried following to make sure browser will not create cashe, but nothing seems to be working.

```
<META http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="10";>
```

Comment: try, `xmlhttp.open("GET","note.xml?t="+(new Date()),false);`

Comment: Welcome, use this solution if work for you, as it will always work, unlike `Math.random()` as you may get same random number in subsequent request where as time will always be unique and it will never fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append a random number to your file:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","note.xml?" + Math.random(),false);
```

This will ensure that the browser always gets the latest version because it will never cache find a cached version that matches the random.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend......i was trying since last 2 days...it worked for me.....Thanks again